# Change event on select with knockout binding, how can I know if it is a real change?

Tags: knockout.js

I am building a permissions UI, I have a list of permissions with a select list next to each permission. The permissions are represented by an observable array of objects which are bound to a select list:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: permissions">
     <div class="permission_row">
          <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
          <select data-bind="value: level, event:{ change: $parent.permissionChanged}">
                   <option value="0"></option>
                   <option value="1">R</option>
                   <option value="2">RW</option>
           </select>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Now the problem is this: the change event gets raised when the UI is just populating for the first time. I call my ajax function, get the permissions list and then the event get raised for each of the permission items. This is really not the behavior I want. I want it to be raised **only when a user really picks out a new value for the permission in the select list**, how can I do that?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Actually **you want to find whether the event is triggered by user or program** , and its obvious that event will trigger while initialization.

The knockout approach of adding `subscription` won't help in all cases, why because in most of the model will be implemented like this

1. init the model with undefined data , just structure  *`(actual KO initilization)`*
2. update the model with initial data  *`(logical init like load JSON , get data etc)`*
3. User interaction and updates

The actual step that we want to capture is changes in 3, but in second step `subscription` will get call ,
So a better way is to add to event change like

```
 <select data-bind="value: level, event:{ change: $parent.permissionChanged}">
```

and detected the event in `permissionChanged` function

```
this.permissionChanged = function (obj, event) {

  if (event.originalEvent) { //user changed

  } else { // program changed

  }

}
```

Comment: I think this should be marked as the correct answer.  I had the exact scenario as described in the question, and I tested passing strings as the Key to the `select` element.  However, even when the initial value of the select matched one of the options, it still triggered the `change` event.  When I implemented this simple `if` block in the handler, everything worked as expected.  Try this method first.  Thanks, @Sarath!

Comment: I like the concept of differentiating between user changed and program changed. This is helpful in everyday cases, especially with knockout where observables are most likely to change value without any user interaction.

Comment: Agree with @Pflugs, differentiating between the event types worked for me and this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: A big thank you for this answer. I was tearing my hair out!

Comment: Getting error as: Unable to process binding "value: function (){return level }"
Message: level is not defined Any idea why?

Comment: def should be an accepted answer... event type property could be used to differentiate triggering of the premissionChanged

Comment: Also used this method to detect whether a user was changing a select rather than another trigger. In my case updating the options values via the "options" binding triggered the "change" event.

Comment: This is not the right answer. As @Michael Best points out, the correct Knockout way to do things is with observables and subscribers. The issue of setting an observable first time and not have it fire any subscribers or event handlers is trivial. It does not require a contrived, and ultimately incorrect, solution like this.

Answer (score 32):

This is just a guess, but I think it's happening because `level` is a number. In that case, the `value` binding will trigger a `change` event to update `level` with the string value. You can fix this, therefore, by making sure `level` is a string to start with.

Additionally, the more "Knockout" way of doing this is to not use event handlers, but to use observables and subscriptions. Make `level` an observable and then add a subscription to it, which will get run whenever `level` changes.

Comment: after 2 hours of digging the cause my form triggering the 'change' event after page load, you guessing saved me.

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea ... I purposefully changed the type coming from the url, so my subscribe function would trigger on page load (I wanted it to process a url var, not just when my dropdown triggered a change). Is there a less hacky way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that may help with this strange behaviour. I couldn't find a better solution than place a button to manually trigger the change event.

EDIT: Maybe a custom binding like this could help:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.changeSelectValue = {

   init: function(element,valueAccessor){

        $(element).change(function(){

            var value = $(element).val();

            if($(element).is(":focus")){

                  //Do whatever you want with the new value
            }

        });

    }
  };
```

And in your select data-bind attribute add:

```
changeSelectValue: yourSelectValue
```

Comment: oh... you mean like a save button?.. not good for me.. i really just need this to work :)

Comment: Edit answer with a better solution (hopefully).

Comment: Hey Ingro, this got flagged (incorrectly) as not an answer. I reworded your initial sentence so flaggers won't accidentally think you're posting a question as an answer. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @jmort253: sorry, that was my fault. It's better not to answer using "I have the same problem too", as this seems to look like you're asking something else. Instead, directly provide a solution to an answer and explain how it works.

Comment: Yeah sorry, my mistake. It was one of the first answer I posted on stackoverflow and didn't know all the rules. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 3):

I use this custom binding (based on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/utsvJ/) fiddle by RP Niemeyer, see his answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10127300/932282) question), which makes sure the numeric value is properly converted from string to number (as suggested by the solution of Michael Best):

Javascript:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.valueAsNumber = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor(),
            interceptor = ko.computed({
                read: function () {
                    var val = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(observable);
                    return (observable() ? observable().toString() : observable());
                },
                write: function (newValue) {
                    observable(newValue ? parseInt(newValue, 10) : newValue);
                },
                owner: this
            });
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: interceptor });
    }
};
```

Example HTML:

```
<select data-bind="valueAsNumber: level, event:{ change: $parent.permissionChanged }">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="1">R</option>
    <option value="2">RW</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use an observable instead of a primitive value, the select will not raise change events on initial binding. You can continue to bind to the change event, rather than subscribing directly to the observable.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty, utilizing a simple flag:

```
var bindingsApplied = false;

var ViewModel = function() {
    // ...

    this.permissionChanged = function() {
        // ignore, if flag not set
        if (!flag) return;

        // ...
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
bindingsApplied = true; // done with the initial population, set flag to true
```

If this doesn't work, try wrapping the last line in a setTimeout() - events are async, so maybe the last one is still pending when applyBindings() already returned.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, this won't work for me because i call the ko.applyBindings when the dom is ready, but my permissions a are being populated to my model at a later stage... so the flag would be true but the problem would still happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I just modified the event handler to check the type of the variable. The type is only set after the user selects a value, not when the page is first loaded.

```
self.permissionChanged = function (l) {
    if (typeof l != 'undefined') {
        ...
    }
}
```

This seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
self.GetHierarchyNodeList = function (data, index, event)
{
    debugger;
    if (event.type != "change") {
        return;
    }        
} 

event.type == "change"
event.type == "load"
```

Comment: 2nd parameter was not index, for me it was event.

Comment: @sairfan add few parameters to the function and find from which parameter you get event using debugger

Answer (score -1):

If you are working using Knockout, use the key functionality of observable functionality knockout.
Use `ko.computed()` method and do and trigger ajax call within that function.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
this.permissionChanged = function (obj, event) {

    if (event.type != "load") {

    } 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Create js component

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'mage/translate'
], function (AbstractField, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return AbstractField.extend({
        defaults: {
            imports: {
                update: 'checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.country_id:value'
            },
            modules: {
                vat_id: '${ $.parentName }.vat_id'


            }
        },

        /**
         * Initializes UISelect component.
         *
         * @returns {UISelect} Chainable.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.vat_id().visible(false);
            return this;
        },
        update: function (value) {
            if(value == 'GB'){
                this.vat_id().visible(true);
            }else{
                this.vat_id().visible(false);

            }
        }
        
        
            
         
      
    });
});
```