# Knockout observable array, get updated item value on change event

Tags: javascript, dom, knockout.js, observable

I'm using knockout.js for an editable table, and I'm trying to fire a validation function when an input field value within the table is changed.

I have tried using an editable computed observable: [change event on select with knockout binding, how can i know if its a real change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078016/change-event-on-select-with-knockout-binding-how-can-i-know-if-its-a-real-chang) (mhu's answer)

I have tried using observable extenders: [KO Extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)

I have also tried using the change event:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JePJh/1/)!

Each time I have tried, only the original value is returned.

What is the standard way to intercept the new value of an `observableArray` item in order to validate the new value?  Is this not bread-and-butter stuff for KO?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation?

Comment: I'd rather not use extra libraries if possible however I will as a last resort.  I thought this would be simple with KO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change your databind statment from

```
data-bind="attr: { value: itemValue  }, event: { change: $parent.itemChanged }"
```

to

```
data-bind="value: itemValue, event: { change: $parent.itemChanged }"
```

working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hztaS/