# how to activate radio button

Tags: knockout.js, radio-button

can anyone help me activate the first radio button as standard

here is my code

```
<div>Wiederholung</div>
<div data-bind="foreach:answers">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="wiederholung" data-bind="click: $root.setChosenAnswer" />
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </label>
        <br />
</div>
<pre data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($root), null, 2)"></pre>
```

js:

```
function Question() {
    var self = this;
    this.answers = ko.observableArray([
        new Answer("Nie", true),
        new Answer("Täglich", false),
        new Answer("Wöchentlich", false)]);

    this.setChosenAnswer = function(wahl) {
        if (wahl !== self.userAnswer()) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.answers(), function(answer)  {
                answer.isChosen(wahl === answer); 
            });

            self.userAnswer(wahl);           
        }
        return true;
    };

    this.userAnswer = ko.observable();

    this.userAnswer.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        alert("Ich moechte mein Termin " + this.userAnswer().name() + " Wiederholen");
    }, this);
}

function Answer(name, isChosen) {
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.isChosen = ko.observable(isChosen);
}

ko.applyBindings(new Question());
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/28kT7/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in html

`<input type="radio" name="wiederholung" data-bind="value: $data.name, checked: $root.defaultChecked, click: $root.setChosenAnswer" />`

in js

`this.defaultChecked = "Nie";`

Answer (score 1):

You may use $index() function to determine index of the item in the array as following:

```
<input type="radio" name="wiederholung" data-bind="click: $root.setChosenAnswer, attr: {checked: $index()==0 }" />
```

But it works with knockout 2.1 and above while in your demo you are using 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

From ["checked" binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html):

> For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked if and only
>   if the parameter value equals the radio button node’s value attribute
>   or the value specified by the checkedValue parameter.

So you need to:

1. Change your `radio` element markup to include `value="true"` because you want it to be selected if you got `true`.
2. Change your `setChosenAnswer` function to return string values either `"true"` or `"false"`.

You may also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127001/binding-true-false-to-radio-buttons-in-knockout-js) for radio binding in KnockoutJS