# Set radio button true load time using knockout js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

Hi please check my code belos

```
    <dl data-bind="foreach: MobileNos"  class="morenumbeList">
                <dd><a data-bind="click: $parent.delete" class="minus">-</a><span class="number" data-bind="text: mobileno"></span>
                    <input id="itemID"  data-bind="checked: $parent.SelectPrimary,attr : { id : 'Primary_' + $index() + ''} " type="radio" name="primary"/></dd>
            </dl>
```

My script :

```
var mobilenoList = function (mobileno, primary) {
    this.mobileno = mobileno;
    this.primary = primary;
};
var MobileSave = function (mobileno, primary) {
    this.mobileno = mobileno;
    this.primary = primary;
}



function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.MobileNos = ko.observableArray();
    self.mobileno = ko.observable("");
    self.primary = ko.observable(false);
    self.itemID = ko.observable(0);

    self.SelectPrimary = ko.computed(function () {
        var mobnums = self.MobileNos();

        $.each(self.MobileNos(), function (index, mobile) {
            if (mobnums[index].primary) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        });

    })

    self.MobileNos.subscribe(function () {
        var mobnums = self.MobileNos();
        for (var i = 0, j = mobnums.length; i < j; i++) {
            var MobileNo = mobnums[i];


            if (!MobileNo.index) {
                MobileNo.index = ko.observable(i + 1);
            } else {
                MobileNo.index(i + 1);
            }

        }
    });


    $.getJSON("/User/GetContactDetails/", { UserID: $('#UserId').val() }, function (MobileNos) {
        $.each(MobileNos.rows, function (index, mobnum) {

            self.MobileNos.push(new mobilenoList(mobnum.mobileno, mobnum.primary));
        })
     });
};

  $(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
  });
```

while I am loading page it should be select radio button , here I can get proper value in "self.MobileNos" but not able to check radio button according that

**EDIT**

```
                        <input id="itemID" value="false"  data-bind="checked: $parent.SelectPrimary,attr : { id : 'Primary_' + $index() + ''} " type="radio" name="primary"/></dd>
       self.SelectPrimary = ko.computed(function () {
        var mobnums = self.MobileNos();

        $.each(self.MobileNos(), function (index, mobile) {
            if (mobnums[index].primary == true) {
                return "true";
            }
            else {
                return "false";
            }
        });

    })
```

Comment: can you please explain `SelectPrimary` logic ?

Comment: if got "mobnums[index].primary" is true than  need to set radio button cheked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ["checked" binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html):

> For radio buttons, KO will set the element to be checked if and only
>   if the parameter value equals the radio button node’s value attribute
>   or the value specified by the checkedValue parameter.

So you need to:

1. Change your `radio` element markup to include `value="true"` because you want it to be selected if you got `true`.
2. Change your `SelectPrimary` function to return string values either `"true"` or `"false"`.

You may also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127001/binding-true-false-to-radio-buttons-in-knockout-js) for radio binding in KnockoutJS

***Update:***

Change your `SelectPrimary` to be like this:

```
self.SelectPrimary = ko.computed(function () {
    var mobnums = self.MobileNos();
    var toreturn = mobnums.some(function (item) {
        return item.primary == true;
    });
    return toreturn.toString()
})
```

The problem here in misuse [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). The value you return is only inside your anonymous function. In other words the retuen value is only for the [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) callback not for your `SelectPrimary` function.
[Array.prototype.some() Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: I have changed radio element markup and Change your SelectPrimary function but still not get response please check EDIT in post

Comment: why you set your radio `value="false"` and not `value="true"` ?

Comment: I have tried first value="true" but did not get proper response that is why set value="false"

Comment: What i understand from your question is that if **any** of your `MobileNos` array objects contain a `primary` with `true` value then the radio button should be selected .. Is that right?

Comment: How can I test if Primary is selected than return only that value, becoz currently it gives me last value as selected