# knockout.js checked not firing subscription in Android 4.2 browser

Tags: javascript, android, knockout.js

The following radio button doesnt fire the subscription for the button to be enabled on the Android browser.  It works on all desktops/browsers/OS and even iPhone but not Android.  Am I missing something?  It works if the input element is switched to a checkbox.  I am using knockout.js 3.2.

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked: accept, disable: files().length == 0" />
<button class="btn submit" data-bind="click: submit, disable: $root.submitting() || !accept() || files().length == 0">Submit</button>

function SubmitTask(classSubmission, options) {
        var self = this;

        self.accept = ko.observable(false);
}
```

Comment: Which KO version are you using? Have you tried to run the official KO testsuit on the device? http://knockoutjs.com/spec/runner.html

Comment: I did run the test suite and all looked good or at least passed, but I dont know if it actually covers this scenario or not with a radio button.

Comment: Are you sure that this setup with the one radio button is working on other browsers? Have you tried to "uncheck" your radio button? You can try to specify the value attribute to "fix" this: `<input type="radio" value="true" data-bind="checked: accept, disable: files().length == 0" />`. Because in KO the checked binding is working differently for radio buttons and you have to work extra to properly work with boolean values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127001/binding-true-false-to-radio-buttons-in-knockout-js

Comment: Yes guarantee its working in everything else, just not this Android browser.

Comment: That was it, I added value="false" and now its working.  Put that as the answer and Ill mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `value="true"` fixed the issue.

Comment: I did there was no answer, what else am I suppose to do, and yes it did answer the question and fix the issue.

Comment: Oops, sorry! This should have failed on a review audit on my side. I didn't notice you have answered your own question.